# Формы имени Георгий "...он же Гоша, он же Жора..."

Tags: имена-собственные

Пожалуй, ни у одного другого имени нет столько форм, сколько у имени Георгий. Вспомним знаменитое: "Он же Гоша, он же Жора, он же Гога". Только официальных "паспортных" вариантов я знаю три: Геогрий, Юрий и Егор.
Вообще, само имя очень распространено среди понтийских греков (сколько я их знаю, почти каждый из них либо Георгий, либо Георгиевич, либо вообще Георгий Георгиевич))), и, как мне сказал один из этих греков, правильная форма имени - Йоргус.
Так вот, почему так вышло, что у имени Георгий аж три официальные мало похожие на оригинал и друг на друга формы и не счесть уменьшительных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Юрий, Георгий, и Егор - имена одного и того же этимологического происхождения. Прочитав такие разногласные ответы, я решила не лезть в русский или греческий, а обратится к английской форме хотя бы одного из этих имён - Джордж. Вот что пишет про это имя [английский этимологический словарь](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=George):

> George masc. personal name, from Late
> Latin Georgius, from Greek Georgos
> "husbandman, farmer," from ge "earth"
> + ergon "work" (see organ).

В русских словарях нашла абсолютно то же самое (смотреть [здесь](http://planeta-imen.narod.ru/imena/georgij.html)). Имя Георгий происходит от греческого Георгос = земледелец (гео = земля, эргон = работа).

Про Юрия ничего интересного вообще не нашла, кроме того, что путём Гюргий и похожих вариантов он рано откололся от Георгия.

Вот про Егора:

> Имя Егор является русским вариантом
> греческого имени Георгий, поэтому
> имеет тоже значение – «земледелец».
> Имя Егор было образовано путем
> перестановки начального звука «г»,
> который был труднопроизносимым для
> русских людей. Имя Егор было
> просторечным, которое в отличие от
> имени Юрий, также являющимся формой
> имени Георгий, чаще использовалось
> среди дворянства и образованных
> сословий в XVII - XIX веках.
> (http://www.kakzovut.ru/names/egor.html)

Насчёт ивритского происхождения имён Георгий и Юрий очень сомневаюсь. Юрий и Урия на самом деле созвучны, но ни один словарь не указывает на эту связь. Имя Ури и сейчас достаточно распространённое в иврите. Но я считаю, что они просто созвучны, но не более того. Что касается Георгия, то назовите мне еврейское имя, созвучное с ним, и может быть, я с Вами соглашусь. :) Я тоже не так плохо разбираюсь и в иврите, и в Библии, но не могу придумать имени, которое бы подходило. К тому же этимологию имён, пришедших путём греческого из иврита, обычно легко проследить. Но ни один словарь не упоминает даже возможности такой связи. Исторически есть возможность ивритских корней, но возможность очень не доказанная. В плане языка её вообще не видно.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ надо искать в особенностях древней фонетики русского языка. Не могло слово начинаться на труднопроизносимое "гео", было неудобно выговаривать. Переиначивали как было удобней, поэтому столько вариантов у одного имени.

Answer (score 2):

Имя  Георгий  действительно  очень  интересно  в  плане   своего  возникновения.  Имя  считается  греческим  и,  соответственно,  из  греческого  и  объясняется.  Для  античных  дохристианских  времён  это  имя  отмечается  как  один  из  эпитетов  Зевса,  но  в  списке   древнегреческих  имён (дохристианских) такого  имени  нет.  В  христианские  времена  это  имя  очень  популярно,  т.к.  это  имя  носит  один  из  самых  популярных   христианских   святых.  Но  Св.  Георгий  Победоносец   называется  уроженцем  Каппадокии.  А  население  это  малоазиатской  области  в  античные  времена  было  разноэтничным.  Там  жили  и  греки  и  армяне,  и  другие  народности.  Причём  армянское  этническое  давление  Каппадокия  испытывала  всегда,  потому  что  граничила  с  собственно  армянскими  областями  на  востоке  и  северо-востоке.  Позднее  появление  имени  Георгий  у  греков  наводит  на  мысль  о  том,  что  это  имя  было  греками  освоено  и  растолковано  с  позиций  греческого  языка (народная  этимология).  Почему  бы  не  поискать  исходный  вариант  в  армянской  антропонимике,  тем  более,  что  христианство  стало  в  Армении  государственной  религией  раньше,  чем  в  Восточной  Римской  империи (традиционная  дата  -  301  г.),  а  собственно  христианизация  армян  началась  ещё  раньше.  Есть популярное и у греков, и у армян, и др. христианских народов имя Григорий. Оно считается греческим и объясняется исходя из греческого языка ( бодрствующий ), но Википедия вводит его в группу собственно христианских имён, т.е. новообразованных, по отношению к дохристианским. Как у нас в 20-30 гг. -- Вилен, Октябрина, Ким и т.п. Может и Георгий входит в ту же группу. Список великих Георгиев открывается Георгием Победоносцем, а он родился в христианской семье.  В  этом  случае  Св. Георгий  мог  быть  каппадокийским  воином,  греком  по  происхождению.

Comment: Армяне, как и евреи, суть семитский народ. У них единое происхождение от гиксосского этноса. В современной Армении до сих пор проживает народность, называющаяся сасунские гайки - осколок некогда грозных покорителей Египта. Армяне и евреи имеют общие фольклорные совпадения. В Ветхом Завете содержатся указания, что прародина евреев находилась на Турецком Кавказе. Ур Халдейский, откуда вышел Авраам, находился именно там, а не в Месопотамии, - сейчас это селения Ура и Урфа. В Месопотамии это другой Ур - шумерский, а не "халдейский". Так что ваша мысль продуктивна.

Comment: Действительно  антропологи  выделяют  армяно-еврейский  тип.  Но  язык  армянский  входит  в  индоевропейскую  семью  языков.  А  древнееврейский (иврит)  в  семитскую.  Может  древние  евреи  заговорили  на  одном  из  семитских  языков,  когда  оказались  в  окружении  семитоговорящих   племён.  Такое  в  истории  бывало.

Comment: @следопыт: Но какое отношение это имеет к делу? Насколько я понимаю, Ваша логическая цепочка такова: древние евреи возможно разговаривали не на иврите, потому что жили не там где считается, и соответственно имя Георгия из Каппадокии, проживавшего рядом с ними, имеет еврейские корни. Проблема в том, что самая ранняя еврейская история написана *на иврите*, и еврейские имена нам известны тоже *из иврита*, и гипотеза о том, что евреи могли говорить на других языках *не доказывает* еврейское происхождение и *опровергает* ивритское происхождение этого имени.

Comment: Вы очень уверены, что это еврейское имя. Возможно и так, но в Ваших доказательствах неправильная последовательность. Вы берёте происхождение из иврита как факт, и потом говорите, что есть возможность что этот факт - правда (но, кстати, может и нет, и в итоге Ваш факт вовсе не факт). Трудно поверить в эту теорию, когда она констатируется без логических доказательств.

Comment: Я  предположил,  что  древнии евреи  могли  говорить  не  на  иврите,  если  допустить,  что  они  вышли  из  районов,  соседствующих  с  древней  Арменией.  И  всё.  С  именем  Георгий  я  это  не  связываю.  Армянское  имя  Геворг  образовано  от  Георгий.  Свою  версию   возникновения  этого  греческого  имени  я  высказал  в  ответе.

Comment: @bernard: я имела в виду больше комментарий Следопыта, хотя и упомянула Ваш комментарий тоже, но только в связи с его словами. А Ваша версия звучит очень резонно.

Answer (score 1):

Георгий – Еоргий – Егорий – Егор

Еоргий – Еорий – Юрий

Русскому гораздо легче произнести ГР, чем РГ

Answer (score 1):

А почему Вы решили, что это одно имя?

В Орфографическом словаре имена Юрий, Георгий и Егор даны отдельными строками.
Ср. Артемий и Артём, Степан и Стефан, которые даны как варианты.

Comment: Юридически это разные имена, а этимологически – одно. Точнее, произошли от одного.

Comment: от какого имени?

Comment: От  имени  Георгий !  Читать, не  читал,  но  наш  преподаватель  языкознания  говорил,  что  произносилось  греками  как  Георгюрий.  Точнее  фонетику  я  передать  не  могу,  но  где-то  так.  Отсюда  русское  Юрий.

Comment: Татьяна Гуса права ! Почему все "решили , что это одно имя ?" Смотрите далее мой ответ на вопрос .

Comment: Юрий,  Георгий,  Егор  не  варианты  одного  имени  -  они  просто  связаны   происхождением  от  одного  имени.

Answer (score 1):

ГЕОРГИЙ и ЮРИЙ разные имена, и я не знаю, как это вышло, что их объединили как варианты. Имя ЮРИЙ это русифицированный вариант еврейского имени УРИЯ, известного по Ветхому Завету. Это имя носил один из командиров царя Давида: царь Давид позарился на его жену Вирсавию (иначе, Варшаву) и подло "подставил" Урию на гибель в одном сражении, после чего завладел Вирсавией. Среди евреев полно Урицких, Юрских и т.п. Среди древнерусских князей имеется несколько Юриев (я помню двух), но Георгиев среди древнерусских персонажей я что-то припомнить не могу. Имя Георгий это скорее всего греческая переделка какого-то еврейского имени: первые христианские святые, как правило, были диаспорными евреями и носили еврейские имена. Это был период, который историки называют иудеохристианством. Жития этих святых писались столетия спустя жизни самих этих святых, когда христианство и иудаизм стали открыто враждебны друг другу, и греческие компиляторы переделывали евреев в греков, переиначивая их имена и биографии. Ранее я уже писал об этом в вопросе об Оксане и Ксении. Имя ЕГОР=ЕГОРИЙ это, скорее всего, другой вариант переделки той же исходной еврейской формы, от которой произошло имя ГЕОРГИЙ. *Приведу вам пример: русское имя АФАНАСИЙ и его украинский аналог ПАНАС. Для обоих этих имён первоначальная еврейская форма ФАНЯ=ПАНЯ (например, Фани Каплан), -* ивритная буква "пэй" чиается двояко - как **Ф** и как* ***П***. Украинцы предпочли свой вариант, более соответствующий исходной еврейской форме, а россияне восприняли общецерковную греко-каноническую форму.

Comment: Георгий  Всеволодович -великий  князь  владимирский,  погиб  в  1238  году  в  бою  на  реке  Сити  во  время  Батыева  нашествия. Варианты  его  имени  в  летописях  -  Гюрги,  Юрий.  Имя  Гюрги  производят  от  греческой  основы  -  Георгий.  Хотя  есть  версии,  указывающие  на  тюркский  исходник.

Comment: Действительно,  интернет-поиск  древнегреческого  имени  Георгиос  ничего  не  дал.  В  списке  новогреских  имён  Георгиос есть (народная  форма  Йоргос).  Но  это  уже  имена  христианские.

Comment: Да, вот у понтийских греков как раз используется эта форма: Йоргус или Йоргос - я могла на слух неточно воспринять.